# Como hacer SELECT Top 1 en MySQL para ultimo registro

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Buenas se que en `SQL Server` se realiza un `query` como este para tomar el ULTIMO registro NO EL PRIMERO

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Tabla
ORDER by ID DESC
```

Así me toma el ultimo registro de la tabla de MSSQL osea SQL server 2008 R2 pero en `MySQL` coloque este y me toma el primer registro ¿Qué debo hacer o qué estoy haciendo mal? Lean el principio ya que me votaron negativo despues de investigar un poco mas

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla
ORDER by ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

DEJANDO en Claro que acado de entender esto, y lo entendi despues de hacer el Post este, que el equivalente a un

```
TOP 1
```

de SQL server es

```
MIN(exprecion)
```

y el ultimo registro es

```
MAX(exprecion)
```

claro esta con su condición.

Comment: No entiendo el porque te trae el primer registro, ese `query` SI o SI debería traerte el último registro, ¿te fijaste cuantos registros hay en tu tabla? ¿quizá el campo `ID` no sea de tipo `autoincrement` y por ello te puede estar generando algún problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No está claro qué has hecho mal. Porque las 2 sentencias son exactamente equivalentes y funcionan perfectamente bien.

---

**`TOP 1` en SQL Server:**

```
create table tbl (
  id int not null primary key,
  texto varchar(50) not null
);

insert into tbl (id, texto) values (1, 'aaa');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (5, 'eee');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (2, 'bbb');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (4, 'ddd');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (3, 'ccc');

select top 1 *
  from tbl
 order by id desc;
```

**Resultado:**

```
id   texto
--   -----
5    eee
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/TMZO36594)</kbd>

---

**`LIMIT 1` con MySQL**

```
create table tbl (
  id int not null primary key,
  texto varchar(50) not null
);

insert into tbl (id, texto) values (1, 'aaa');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (5, 'eee');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (2, 'bbb');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (4, 'ddd');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (3, 'ccc');

select *
  from tbl
 order by id desc
 limit 1;
```

**Resultado:**

```
id   texto
--   -----
5    eee
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/FECJY67444)</kbd>

---

Como puedes ver, ambas consultas funcionan bien y devuelven el mismo resultado.

Por otro lado, la consulta que pusistes como la respuesta a tu pregunta:

```
SELECT MAX(id) *
FROM Tabla
```

... no es válido en absoluto, ni siquiera corre, como se puede observar aquí: <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/PDOKU13026)</kbd>

Tal vez quisistes decir:

```
SELECT MAX(t.id), t.*
FROM Tabla t
```

... pero aunque por lo menos ahora corre, esta consulta te puede dar resultados completamente erróneos, como puedes observar en la demo siguiente:

```
create table tbl (
  id int not null primary key,
  texto varchar(50) not null
);

insert into tbl (id, texto) values (1, 'aaa');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (5, 'eee');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (2, 'bbb');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (4, 'ddd');
insert into tbl (id, texto) values (3, 'ccc');

select max(t.id), t.*
  from tbl t;
```

**Resultado:**

```
max(t.id)  id   texto
---------  --   -----
5          1    aaa
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/AQQT82919)</kbd>

Comment: Error amigo su resultado es erroneo ¿no deberia mostrar el ID mas alto solamente? es decir asi cmo se haria en MSSQL;        SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table WHERE Usuario = @User ORDER By ID DESC  su resultado deberia ser ID = 5 y texto EEE por lo tanto su consulta es erronea ella solo muestra el primer resultado mas NO el ultimo Gracias por ser tan amable

Comment: ¿De cual consulta estás hablando? Creo que con los enlaces que dejé, está mas que claro que `LIMIT 1` funciona de forma idéntica a `TOP 1` en MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo estás tomando el orden descendente y eso te tomaría el último registro ingresado, teniendo en cuenta que el id sea auto  incrementable. El query quedaría algo como esto:

`SELECT * FROM Tabla ORDER by ID ASC LIMIT 1`

Esto te traería el registro más viejo. Pero ten en cuenta como va creciendo el campo ID

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa hermosamente florida:

```sql
SELECT * FROM libros WHERE Precio = (SELECT MIN(Precio) FROM libros);
```

La virtud principal de esta query es que si, por ejemplo, dos libros tienen el mismo precio mínimo, se muestran los dos registros. En cambio "LIMIT 1" sólo nos presenta un resultado.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/316438)