# Consultar ultimo registro de una tabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, tablas, sql

estoy tratando de consultar el ultimo registro de una tabla.

Mi tabla se llama: divisa

dentro de las cuales tengo dos Columnas: dolar, euro

Ahora bien, esta es mi consulta para traer el ultimo registro de la columna dolar, por ejemplo:

```
 <?php 
 $sql="SELECT * from divisa where dolar= (SELECT MAX(dolar) ";
 $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
 while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
```

Debo tener algun error en mi consulta, ya que cuando me voy a la pagina donde estoy treyendo esos datos, me advierte que hay un error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> boolean given in

Comment: ¿Te refieres al último registro de la tabla o bien al registro con el valor más alto de Dolar?

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, con tu pregunta me di cuenta del primer error, me refiero al ultimo registro de la tabla.

Comment: Deberías poner la definición de la tabla. El último registro está en función de la clave primaria. Si solo tienes las columnas Euro y Dolar, necesitarás al menos un campo autonumérico para hacer referencia a una fila concreta.

Comment: ok, debo crear otra columna que la pudiera llamar: id_divisa y esta que se autoicremente correcto?

Comment: Correcto, es necesaria para identificar de forma inequívoca la fila

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como hacer SELECT Top 1 en MySQL para ultimo registro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41880/como-hacer-select-top-1-en-mysql-para-ultimo-registro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores. El primero es de sintaxis, puesto que falta terminar la sentencia sql

Donde

```
$sql="SELECT * from divisa where dolar= (SELECT MAX(dolar) ";
```

Debería ser

```
$sql="SELECT * from divisa where dolar= (SELECT MAX(dolar) from divisa)";
```

El segundo error es de concepto, pues pretendes tener el último dato de la conversión Euro-Dolar, no los datos dónde el dolar tuvo mayor valor. Es decir, requieres buscar la última fila con datos. Para ello debes ser capaz de distinguir entre las diferentes filas, por una clave primaria, para poder localizar la última fila.

En la tabla, debes crear un campo autoincrementable (p.e. id_divisa) que sea clave primaria. Con este campo podrás identificar de forma inequívoca cada fila.

Una vez tengas este campo, la consulta será:

```
select * from divisa where id_divisa in (select MAX(id_divisa) from divisa)
```

Que en tu código aparecerá como

```
 <?php 
 $sql="select * from divisa where id_divisa in (select MAX(id_divisa) from divisa)";
 $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
 while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
```

Comment: En realidad esto responde la siguiente pregunta de OP... la pregunta actual de OP es un error tipografico, le falta un )

Comment: Tienes razón, lo expliqué en los comentarios y no en la respuesta, ahora lo he corregido

Comment: Si es error tipografico, se cierra como error tipografico... No se en mysql, pero estamos seguros que un campo autoincremental siempre el ultimo es el mayor? en caso de tener multiples puntos de entrada no hace un cache de valores??? la mejor forma, siempre, es poner la fecha de ingreso...

Comment: Excelente, lo solucioné y gracias por aclararme los conceptos roger, saludos!.