# Consultar el ultimo pedido de venta de un producto

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Tengo una base de datos de PrestaShop en la cual puedo consultar cual es el ultimo pedido realizado si le paso un determinado id de producto con esta consulta

```
    select max(po.id_order) as ultimo_pedido,
    inner join prestashop.ps_order_detail pod on po.id_order = pod.id_order
    where pod.product_id = 1120
```

El problema viene cuando quiero que me muestre el ultimo pedido de todos los productos que tengo en la tabla ps_product, si utilizo el max, me muestra un único registro y yo quiero que me muestre el máximo por cada uno de los artículos

He intentado usar la clausula LIMIT 1 pero quiero que me limite a 1 el resultado por cada articulo

Ejemplo (uso solo 3 artículos de prueba):

```
    select 
    #max(po.id_order) as ultimo_pedido,
    po.id_order, po.date_add, 
    DATEDIFF(now(), po.date_add) as dias, pod.product_id, pod.product_quantity
    from prestashop.ps_orders po inner join prestashop.ps_order_detail pod 
    on po.id_order =   pod.id_order 
    where pod.product_id in (1120, 1121,1122)
    order by po.id_order DESC limit 1
```

Cualquier ayuda me seria de mucha utilidad.

Comment: Te paso un enlace de stackoverflow que explican [cómo hacer SELECT top 1 en SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41880/como-hacer-select-top-1-en-mysql-para-ultimo-registro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrías realizar lo siguiente:

```
select  pod.descripcion as Producto, ISNULL(max(po.id_order),'') as ultimo_pedido,
inner join prestashop.ps_order_detail pod on po.id_order = pod.id_order
group by pod.descripcion order by pod.descripcion
```

Puedes personalizar tu filtro por un grupo de productos, o por productos activos o inactivos... según lo que requieras

Answer (score 1):

con la ayuda de @vidal LP he podido hacer la consulta y queda de la siguiente forma

```
select pod.product_id as Producto, max(pod.id_order) as ultimo_pedido
from prestashop.ps_product pp
inner join prestashop.ps_order_detail pod on pp.id_product = pod.product_id 
group by pod.product_id;
```

Espero sea de utilidad